# How to disable submit button after click?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to disable button after click by using following code but it is not working.

View

```
<button class="button button-text-only" onclick=" $('#MyForm').submit() ">Create </button>
```

js

```
//inside document.ready
$('#MyForm').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

TIA

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: I see a `button` not an `input submit`. You may want to change that.

Comment: If on submit reloads the page then is logical to loose attr disabled..

Comment: @Spokey is correct. And also I think that your button is not inside the form because of your javascript code. So, the second argument of the selector may be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mH8X9/1/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: you better use prop("disabled",true)

Comment: Thank you all for help. @Arko Elsenaar I tried your code but it is not working.

Comment: Pawal, you are right. I have modified my answer and set up a really simple demo so you can see it in action. You can use this in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would change your button to the following code

```
<button id="button-id" class="button button-text-only">Create </button>
```

then bind the click event this way instead:

```
$('#button-id').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from being submitted

    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    //process form with ajax otherwise your page is just going to reload and the button won't be disabled anymore
    var form = $('#MyForm');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.get(0).action,
        type: form.get(0).method,
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
           //do finished stuff here
           alert('done');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is the best solution also we can add some AJAX properties, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to disable the button ...

```
$('#MyForm').on('click', function () {
    $("#myButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Then if you need to enable you can remove disabled as below...

```
$("#myButton").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()` here. Try `.prop('disabled', true)` and `.prop('disabled', false)` instead...